# R - Loop through different matrices without using loop ! Help to simply a code

Tags: r, loops, matrix, tapply

So I have two separate matrix (mat1 and mat2) 
and I need to go through them in order to make a check. 
I need to store the results into a third matrix.

I feel that my code is very long for the purpose.

I wanted to have some of your suggestion to avoid looping.

So my first matrix looks like this (dput in the end)

```
  wit5.001 wit5.002 wit5.003 wit5.004 wit5.005 wit5.006 wit5.007 wit5.008 wit5.009 wit5.010
 [1,]        1        1        1        1        1        1        1            1        1        1
 [2,]        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
 [3,]        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
 [4,]        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
 [5,]        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        0        1        1
 [6,]        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        0        0        0
 [7,]        0        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
 [8,]        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
 [9,]        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
[10,]        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
```

My second matrix has a similar structure.

Here I create my third matrix - in order to store the results of the checking.

```
matCheck <- matrix('ok', ncol = ncol(mat1), nrow = nrow(mat1))
```

Here is my loop - that I would like to avoid

```
for(j in 1:ncol(mat1)){
  for(i in 1:nrow(mat1)){

    if(mat1[i,j] == 1 & mat2[i,j] == 1) 
    {matCheck[i,j] <- 'ok'}  

    if(mat1[i,j] != 1 & mat2[i,j] == 1) 
    {matCheck[i,j] <- '!'}  

      }
   }
```

The result of the check

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" 
 [2,] "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" 
 [3,] "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" 
 [4,] "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" 
 [5,] "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" 
 [6,] "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "!"  "!"  "ok" 
 [7,] "!"  "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" 
 [8,] "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" 
 [9,] "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" 
[10,] "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok"
```

Any suggestions ?

Here is matrix 1

```
mat1 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(10L, 
 10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("wit5.001", "wit5.002", "wit5.003", 
"wit5.004", "wit5.005", "wit5.006", "wit5.007", "wit5.008", "wit5.009", 
"wit5.010")))
```

Here is matrix 2

```
mat2 = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("wit5.020", "wit5.021", "wit5.022", 
"wit5.023", "wit5.024", "wit5.025", "wit5.026", "wit5.027", "wit5.028", 
"wit5.029")))
```

Comment: @Frank - Sorry my fault - you are right, they are not suppose to be different dimensions (I made a mistake in my subset). I corrected the code.

Comment: I am going to try your propositions guys thanks

Comment: is it that simple ! oh no... After all the effort in put in my loops ;) Thanks @Frank - put it as an answer then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the example given, the result can be constructed as

```
matCheck <- ( mat1 | !mat2 )
```

This is equivalent to initializing `matCheck` to true and then filling in false where `!mat1 & mat2` (as in the OP's loop). The parentheses are optional, but make it easier to read (I think).